# Chat Bot Hero card title message not wrapped properly

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I have created hero card for messages with prompt buttons from qna maker. The hero card embedded response has a title and buttons. The buttons are displayed properly and worked as expected, but the title words are not wrapped properly.

```
if (resResult) {
var answer = resResult.answer;
var resultContext = resResult.context;
var prompts = resultContext && resultContext.prompts;

if (prompts && prompts.length) {
    var card = CardFactory.heroCard(
        answer,
        [],
        prompts.map(prompt => ({
            type: 'messageBack',
            title: prompt.displayText,
            displayText: prompt.displayText,
            text: prompt.displayText,
            value: {
                qnaId: prompt.qnaId
            }
        }))
    );
    answer = MessageFactory.attachment(card);
}

    await context.sendActivity(answer);

}
```

The output response in chat window / Emulator is

[image]

The title text which is displayed needs to wrapped and font style and color should align with common text styles of chat bot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want that text to be the title of the card, or would you be satisfied having it as the text of the card?

Comment: Are you still working on this?